# how can i take multiple div and change the distance in between of them

Tags: html, css, margin

i have 4 div's that i made into a circle using this css`background-color:transparent;border:2px solid #045990;border-radius: 50%;width: 1.5%;height: auto;padding-top: 1.3%;`
how can i combine the div's and use margin-bottom to like change the distance in between them without just using top:"#"px. It would be very helpful if someone could help me or like make a quick example

Comment: Please add a [example].

Comment: would you want a functionality similar to `gap` (grid, or flex)? I didn't understand, can you say more details! thanks.